# What qualifies a string to be considered an Internet suffix?

Tags: dns, internet

Generally, most people would consider `compute-1.amazonaws.com` to be the `compute-1` subdomain on `amazonaws.com`

But apparently that's not the case at all.  According to the [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat), `compute-1.amazonaws.com` is a suffix just like `com` or `net`.

Why is this and how does this make sense?  Is it completely arbitrary and just dependent on whether or not it is included in the Public Suffix List, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 1):

this subdomain exist just as SOA entry.

```
root:~# dig  compute-1.amazonaws.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> @dns-external-master.amazon.com compute-1.amazonaws.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 32744
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;compute-1.amazonaws.com.       IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
compute-1.amazonaws.com. 5      IN      SOA     dns-external-master.amazon.com. hostmaster.amazon.com. 2013092946 180 60 2592000 5

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 204.74.108.1#53(204.74.108.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Jun  4 11:37:42 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 115
```